# Generating Joi validation a Sequelize model

Tags: node.js, validation, express, sequelize.js, joi

I have developed an API using `expressjs` and `Sequelize` is the ORM I have used. I want to integrate [express-validation](https://github.com/AndrewKeig/express-validation) to my API to validate the request body and params. The `express-validation` framework uses the Joi validation rules. But as I have already defined the validation rules in my `Sequalize` model, I' don't like to redefine validation rules using Joi for request body validations.

I'm just wondering if there's any method or library to generate Joi validation rules based on validations defined in Sequelize model. Else, what would be the best approach to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [joi-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-sequelize) ?

Answer (score 2):

This question is too old however this answer maybe helpful for those newbies who are learning the language or maybe started working with sequelize

Sequelize provides validation by default. You can look into the docs

[Sequelize Validation docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html#per-attribute-validations.)

However if you want to provide your own custom validators with custom "pretty" messages. You can always use the

> @hapi/joi

package the "normal" way. joi-sequelize or sequelize-joi are not required just to provide custom error message.(period)

```
function validateData(datas) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        user_name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
        user_address: Joi.string().required()
    });
    return schema.validate(datas);
}
```

and then validate the data using

```
    const { error } = validateData(req.body);
```

which catches if any properties fails the validation.